# Como añadir variable python a un select

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, python-2.7

tengo este trabajo y me gustaria pasarle la variable python fecha como campo al select y luego al insert. Como podria hacer eso?

```
fecha=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    cur1= conn.cursor()
        cur1.execute("select %s, id, codigo from tabla;", fecha)
        result = cur1.fetchall()

`   

    cursor2=conn2.cursor()

    for fila in result:
        print(fila)#fila[0])
    fecha, id, codigo = fila
cursor2.execute("Insert into dbo.clientes  (fecha, id, codigo) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s)" % (fecha, id, codigo)
 cursor2.commit()
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> in escape_args
> raise exc.ProgrammingError("Unsupported param format: {}".format(parameters)) pyhive.exc.ProgrammingError: Unsupported param
> format: 2023-09-06

Comment: ¿Qué estás intentando aquí?: `"select %s, id, codigo from tabla;"` . Cuando Python reemplace la variable `fecha` en el código, quedará: `"select 2023-09-06, id, codigo from tabla;"`. Obviamente eso marcará error.

Comment: complementando, debería ser "select '%s' as fecha, id, codigo from tabla;", ya lo probaste?

Comment: Coincido con @aeportugal , La consulta quedara tal cual como el te indica. La variable ya cargada podrias usarla en un select concatenando tu variable parseandola a String. Ejemplo: cur1.execute("select fecha, id, codigo from tabla WHERE fecha LIKE '"+ str(fecha) +"';")

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás viendo se debe al hecho de que estás pasando la fecha directamente en la consulta SQL como una cadena formateada. Para evitar este error y realizar la inserción correctamente, puedes utilizar placeholders (%s) en la consulta SQL y proporcionar los valores como una tupla al método execute de tu cursor, debes hacerlo de esta forma.

```
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2  # Asumiendo que estás utilizando PostgreSQL, ajusta esto según tu base de datos

fecha = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Realiza la consulta SQL con placeholders
consulta_select = "SELECT %s, id, codigo FROM tabla;"
cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur1.execute(consulta_select, (fecha,))
result = cur1.fetchall()

cursor2 = conn2.cursor()

# Itera a través de los resultados y realiza la inserción
for fila in result:
    fecha, id, codigo = fila
    cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.clientes (fecha, id, codigo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (fecha, id, codigo))
    conn2.commit()  # Guarda los cambios en la base de datos

# Cierra los cursores y conexiones
cur1.close()
cursor2.close()
conn.close()
conn2.close()
```